I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
This is my contoller
 @PostMapping("/MatchOptimalLocationInfo/{tenant}")
public ResponseEntity<String> matchOptimalLocationInfo(@PathVariable("tenant") String tenantCode,
                                                       @RequestBody MatchOptimalLocationRequestTO matchOptimalLocationRequestTO,
                                                       @RequestAttribute(name = Constant.REQUEST_USER, required = false) UserTO userTO,
                                                       @RequestAttribute(name = "additionalParam", required = false) Map<String, Object> additionalParam) {
    if (userTO != null && Constant.TRUE.equalsIgnoreCase(ssoEnabled)) {
        tenantCode = userTO.getTenantCode();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(matchOptimalLocationRequestTO.getPersonId())) {
            logger.debug("Empty personId in request, user userTo's personId.");
            matchOptimalLocationRequestTO.setPersonId(userTO.getPersonId());
        }
    }
    logger.debug("matchOptimalLocationInfo, tenantCode:" + tenantCode + ", request param:" + JSON.toJSONString(matchOptimalLocationRequestTO));

This is not a mandatory issue, it really comes up during pressure testing. I'm guessing it's a network fluctuation, but that would require proof.I tried to use a cutout to print the contents of the requestbody ahead of time, and finally realized that the error was reported before I went into this cutout.
    org.springframework.http.converter.Http MessageNotReadableException:I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageCoerterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:218)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBoMethodProcessor.readWithMessage Converters(RequestResponse BodyMethodProciessorjava:157)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodiProcessor.java:130
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverCompepsite.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandler Method.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvodtableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.jiava:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invoke HandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapteer.java:870
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMapppingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter,java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandler MethodAdapteandle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter,java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(D)ispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequeest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FramevvorkServlet.java:881)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(AppliicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.Application FilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFiterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicIterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricslFilter.filterAndRecord Metrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilteilterAndRecord Metrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WeebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequest Filter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.Application FilterChain.internalDoFilter(Applilication FilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFiernal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequest Filter.doFilter(OncePerRequest Filter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.Application FilterChain.internal DoFilIter(Application FilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.Application FilterChain.doFilter(AApplication ilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContext Filter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncelPerRequest ilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.Application FilterChain.internalDoFilter(Application FilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationfilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutForm ContentFilter.doFilterlnternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework,web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerkRequestFilterjava:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internal DoFilter(AppliionFilterChainjava:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFil166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterlnternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilterjava:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePer RequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequest Filter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internal DoFilter(AppliChainjava:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at datadog.trace.instrumentation.springweb.HandlerMappingResourceNameFilter.doFilterInternal(HandlerMappingResourceNameFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilterjava:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(AppliccationFilterChain.java:193
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterlnternal(CharacterEncoding Filterjava:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilterjava:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicChainjava:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperVal
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authenticato
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke $original$nkEopBDG(StandardHostValve java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke$original$nkEopBDGSaccBU(StandardHostValvejava)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve$auxiliaryScoAFcall(UnknowrSource
at org.apache.skywalking.apm.agent.core.plugin.interceptor.enhance.instMetter.intercept(InstMethodsInterjava:86
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.jav
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.jav
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccess.og Valve.invoke(AbstractAccesvejava:650
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapterjava:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http 11.Http11 Processor.service(Http11 Processor,javva:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLiightjava:66
at org.apache.coyote AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process (AbstractProtocoljava:790)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpointjava:1459
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorB:ase.java:49
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPooExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer,java:722)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access $300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11 inputBuffer$SocketinputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1072)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentitylnputFilter.java:140)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:261)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11 inputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBufferjava:261)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBufferjava:326
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBufferjava:642
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.readByte(InputBuffer,java337)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyotelnputStream.read(CCoyoteInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FilterlnputStream.read(FilterlnputStream.java:83)
at java.io.PushbacklnputStream.read(PushbacklnputStream.java:139)
at oro.sprinoframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessaoeConverterMethodAraumentResolverSEmptvBodvCheckinaHttplnout:Messaoe.<init>(AbstractMessaoeConverterMethodArgumentResolver.iava:319)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation. AbstractMlessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageCConverters(Abstract MessageConverterMethodArgumentRessolver.java:192
...72 more


Are you able to add more logging to determine which input is correlated to the issue?
